Which windows folder should I restore to get back my administrator account?
First of all, I am not a system administrator.
I have a dedicated windows 2016 server at a known provider, I inactivated the Administrator account and created a new account.
Like a newbee, before testing the connection with the new admin user, I disconnected.
And I can not reconnect, the password is wrong.
I have system backup on my acronis panel.
Which folder should I restore to get back the Administrator account ?
Is it possible ?
I dont have any access to server except the backup console.

Once a user profile is deleted it cannot be restored. If you have the user profile directory just take ownership of the folder. This absolutely CANNOT be done as anything other then an Administrator. Your question title doesn’t match the description of your problem.

How did you inactivate the admin account? How you did this will determine the correct way to restore it.  Please add this information to your question, and do not post it as a comment down here.

By “backup console” you mean WinRE?


Which folder should I restore to get back the Administrator account ?

Windows user account information is stored in \Windows\System32\config\SAM.
The config\ directory is where your Registry's HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE is stored. This means:

Most files in it are always in-use while the OS is running, and restoring them from backup needs Windows to be shut down first.

Only do a directory restore if the backup is fresh – restoring config\ from an old backup will make it go out of sync with the rest of the system. Restoring just the single config\SAM file might be a better idea.

If the datacenter provides console (KVM) access and lets you boot a custom ISO, you can use chntpw (found in various Linux distros or the special "ntpasswd" image) to unlock accounts or reset their passwords.


